# Abstract Syntax Tree and Control Flow Graph Generator Tool for C++ source code

Tags: c++, static-analysis

Can you suggest some tool that generates both Abstract Syntax Tree and Control Flow Graph from C++ source code?

Answer (score 1):

My company's product, the [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](https://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html?site=SoftwareRecommendations), and its [C++ Front End](https://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html?site=SoftwareRecommendations), can do this.

The front end link shows renderings of example ASTs as well and control data flow graphs.  It handles C++17.

Nobody wants "just" a control flow graph.  DMS also provides a vast amount of machinery for building custom source code analyzers and transformers (building on the rest of its capabilities for parsing and flow analysis), enabling one to build tools a lot more easily than if one contemplates building such a custom tool from scratch, even if it uses DMS's standard C++ analyses.